# C++ way of detecting powerstate changes in Windows for a desktop app

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I've been looking everywhere for some information as to how one might go about registering for power state changes in a C++ application. I don't have a window handle and the program does not always run in as a service. I see that there are powerstate broadcasts available to register for but I cant seem to find anyway to get to them. Any one have any idea?

Once I've received a power state change, I plan on informing all connected users to that machine.

Comment: You need a window or a service to [receive power notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/registering-for-power-events). The only other option is to continuously poll the current state, and that is not a good idea. What is stopping you from creating a window? You can create a hidden message-only window if you don't have a GUI window to use.

Comment: Thanks for the verification. Creating a window seems to be where I'm heading. This is a server application without a GUI so I wasn't sure if there was a better way to do this. Appreciate it.